# Android test Fragmen with mock ViewModel using Hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt, mockk

I´m developing an app using Hilt, all works fine but when I try to run some Espresso test on a device running on below Android P I have encountered an issue.

The problem comes when I try to mock (using Mockk) the ViewModel so I can unit test my Fragment. When the Fragment will try to instanciate te ViewModel I got a NullPointerException when the ViewModel is being created. The NPE is thrown on the method `setTagIfAbsent`. The problem is that this method is package private as you can see on [ViewModel source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-main/lifecycle/lifecycle-viewmodel/src/main/java/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModel.java), so it can not be mocked on Android < P.

I have tried by using the [Kotlin All-Open plugin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/all-open-plugin.html), it has helped on mocking the ViewModel and stubing it public methods. I try to stub the `setTagIfAbsent` by using the mockk private stubbing, like this:

```
every{
    myViewModelMock["setTagIfAbsent"](any<String>,any())
} answers {secondArg()}
```

But when `setTagIfAbsent` is called, the real method is invoked, throwing the NPE because the `ViewModel.mBagOfTags` is null because the class is a mock.

The rest of the code is the following:

ViewModel:

```
@OpenForTesting
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor MyViewModel(private val dependency: Dependency): ViewModel(){
    //Rest of the code
}
```

Fragment:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MyFragment: Fragment(){
    private val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels()
    //Rest of the code
}
```

Test class:

```
@HiltAndroidTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MyFragmentTest {

    @Bind
    @MockK
    lateinit var viewModel: MyViewModel

    @get:Rule
    var hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    @Before
    fun prepareTest(){
        MockkAnnotations.init(this)
        hiltRule.inject()
        launchFragmentInHiltContainer<MyFragment>()
    }

    @Test
    fun testThatWillMakeAViewModelInvokation(){
         onView(withId(R.id.button)).perform(click())
         //Assume that button will make the ViewModel be called and created by the delegate
         //When this happens the NPE is thrown
    }
}
```

The method launchFragmentInHiltContainer comes from [here (Hilt sample app)](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/dev-hilt/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/HiltExt.kt#L38).

If you look at the [Mockk Android documentation](https://mockk.io/ANDROID.html) it is said that < Android P the private methods can not be mocked (it is also said for finals, but the OpenClass plugin fix that problem).

Does anyone have an idea of how can I workaround this or how to fix the test?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which library are you using for the `@Bind` annotation?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of mocking `setTagIfAbsent` you can mock `mBagOfTags` using reflection on already mocked instance of ViewModel.

```
setInternalFieldValue(mockedViewModel, "mBagOfTags", HashMap<String, Any>())
```

```
fun setInternalFieldValue(target: Any, fieldName: String, value: Any, javaClass: Class<in Any> = target.javaClass) {
    try {
        val field = javaClass.getDeclaredField(fieldName)
        field.isAccessible = true
        field.set(target, value)
    } catch (exception: NoSuchFieldException) {
        val superClass = javaClass.superclass
        if (superClass != null) {
            setInternalFieldValue(target, fieldName, value, superClass)
        } else {
            throw RuntimeException("Field $fieldName is not declared in a hierarchy of this class")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, it works, though it is ugly, isn't there a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

If you use mockk(relaxed = true) this problem is solved

Comment: THIS right here was the answer. Thanks!